# How to test currency localisation using Revenuecat in android

Tags: android, ios, flutter, localization, revenuecat

I am working on flutter and Integrated Revenuecat with Google and Apple, In Apple I can easily test the currency localization by creating a user account with different countries in the Apple sandbox account, Then I can easily test my app.
But In Android how I can test it? because there are no sandbox accounts like an apple. how I can use other countries' based email to test the localization.

Here is the code from where I am getting the Currency.

```
Future<Product?> getLocalProduct() async {
    try {
      Offerings? offerings = await Purchases.getOfferings();

      if (offerings.current == null) {
        print('No Offer available');
      } else {
        Product price = offerings.current!.monthly!.product;
        return price;
      }
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      print(e.message.toString());
    }
    return null;
  }

getLocalProductPrice() async {
    Product? product = await SubscriptionService.instance.getLocalProduct();
    currencySymbol.value = product!.priceString;
    perDayPrice.value = product.price / 30;
  }
```